Unable to render widget dynamically in Flutter using Provider?
I am trying to display widget(s) dynamically based on the empty/non-empty state of a TextField widget. Below is the code I've written. But the code does not dynamically create the widget even when I type in text in the TextField of Tax Percentage. This is unexpected. Here, I am also not sure if we can late assign the Provider the way I have done in the code.
What I've tried. I've tried declaring the boolean variable isEmptyTaxPercentage in the Provider class as static and set using static access method in the onChanged of the TaxPercentage TextField. But, as no notifyListeners() function was called, perhaps, this also did not work as expected: the intended widget didn't show up dynamically.
Update 01: Fixed the code below. Now it works as intended. The only question remaining is declaration of the provider as late MyTaxProvider myTaxProvider in the State class is valid and good practice or not?
The code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MyTaxProvider>(
          create: (context) => MyTaxProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Provider Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyTaxProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isEmptyTaxPercentage = true;

  void setTaxPercentageEmptynessState(bool value) {
    isEmptyTaxPercentage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final TextEditingController costController;
  late final TextEditingController taxPercentageController;
  late final TextEditingController taxAmountController;

  late MyTaxProvider myTaxProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    costController = TextEditingController();
    taxPercentageController = TextEditingController();
    taxAmountController = TextEditingController();

    myTaxProvider = Provider.of<MyTaxProvider>(context, listen: false);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    costController.dispose();
    taxPercentageController.dispose();
    taxAmountController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                const Expanded(
                  child: Text("Cost:"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: costController,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Expanded(
                  child: Text("Tax precentage (%):"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: taxPercentageController,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        myTaxProvider.setTaxPercentageEmptynessState(true);
                      } else {
                        myTaxProvider.setTaxPercentageEmptynessState(false);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Consumer<MyTaxProvider>(
              builder: (context, provider, child) {
                if (provider.isEmptyTaxPercentage) {
                  return Container();
                } else {
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        child: Text("Tax Amount:"),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: taxAmountController,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            const Text("Other widget(s)."),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Declaring the provider as late is not recommended you should probably instead use it like below inside your build method
final myTaxProvider = Provider.of<MyTaxProvider>(context, listen: false);

That way your code is more clear and avoid potential errors regarding late initialization.

But if declared within build method, I do not have the access to the myTaxProvider object outside build method: which I need in the TextField of tax percentage as seen in my code. So, what alternative am I remained with?

I see the the TextField of tax percentage is inside the MyHomePage build method which I have tested and worked perfectly.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final myTaxProvider = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
return Scaffold( // the TextField of tax percentage);

If you could write the reasons for why not, I will accept the answer. Thank you.

I have used the "late MyProvider provider" declaration and then assigned it in the initState method, just as you have done, in multiple places in a production app and it has never caused problems. Just as you have done, you set "listen" to false, and then only use the provider instance to update values, not to listen to changes.

It is safer to declare providers as final in the build method. Using late has potential errors such as late initialization errors, rebuild issues and also makes it hard to manage the  lifecycles of both the widget and the provider.
